# Defacto Project Template for Python Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

Can someone recommend a project skeleton for python tornado? I suppose it's easy enough to roll my own but I'm curious what else is out there since (obviously) others have been down this road before.

Answer (score 3):

You can find mine on https://github.com/bastienlabelle/tornado-base-app It's worth what it's worth (so it's probably not the best skeleton project out there), but I use it everytime I start a tornado app.

Answer (score 3):

I tried using [Bueda's boilerplate](https://github.com/bueda/tornado-boilerplate) which is OK, although it turned out to be overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the [Introduction To Tornado sample codes](https://github.com/Introduction-to-Tornado/Introduction-to-Tornado) to be extremely useful and well written. And I don't even own the book.

Answer (score 0):

Tornado comes with a good number of examples and the source is well documented with a few code snipits as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would [this web.py code skeleton](http://webpy.org/skeleton/0.3) work for tornado, too?

Answer (score 0):

in fact, i start over from the one in the doc :

https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```